# Unable to get selected text options in dropdown loaded from text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a dropdown populated from a text file. The code works fine in my pc but on the hosted site I am not able to get the selected option. Below is the html code:

`<select id="political_party"><option></option></select>`

Below is the JS code:
`$("#political_party").load("resources/political_parties.txt"); var political_party1=$('#political_party option:selected').text();`
What could be the problem? the website is hosted on Microsoft Azure

Comment: use this instead `var political_party1 = $('#political_party').children('option:selected').text();`

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman Thanks for the comment. I tried the solution you suggested but my problem has not been fixed yet been fixed it still persists when the website is live.